# How to work with laravel activity log with in application (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, activitylog

I have to save activity in log.

I have radio buttons, if enable is checked, then logs should be stored in activity_logs.

How can I achieve this and Where should I do this, in base controller or new controller.

Answer (score 0):

Read up about the laravel logging functionality https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#logging

You can write directly to the laravel log like this with the built in facade:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info('activity_log:'.$itemToLog);
```

You can put this in the controller you want to add the logging information too.